# Looking for a blood glucose data set for predictive algorithm

Tags: data-request, medical

Student in data analysis and diabetes, I'm looking for a data set that contains the features below to test some algorithm of prediction (random forest). Where can I get such a data set, please?

The features:

- Continuous blood sugar
- recent food out to several hours depending on the type and how much
  activity levels
- stress levels
- illness
- basal and bolus insulin rate (the patient wears a pump)

Comment: Welcome to the Open Data Stackexchange. Answers will be public and appear here below your question. You can configure your account to get an email notification when an answer arrives. Please don't ask for answers to be emailed to you; I will edit your email adress out of the question